# Scala, Spray and Path

Tags: scala, spray

How I can path different url: "some.host/prefix/params/params" and "some.host/prefix/params/params/123" ?

I try this:
`get {
  path ("prefix" / Segments) { ss => complete (ss) }
  path ("prefix" / Segments / IntNumber) { (ss, num) => complete (num)}
}`

but `(ss, num) => complete (num)` never executed.

Trick like `Segments / «i» ~ IntNumber ~ PathEnd` for url "some.host/prefix/params/params/i123" don't work too.

Comment: maybe you should match `"prefix" / Segments / IntNumber` before `"prefix" / Segments`

Comment: i try this too, but it's not work.